# Android call onNewIntent() of homescreen launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I learned that the Android launcher resets the homescreen to the default page when onNewIntent() is called. I know that onNewIntent() is called when the activity receives another start intent while it's already in the foreground. Is there a way to call the onNewIntent() of the activity when it's in the background?

I have tried several flags like FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT but none seems to call onNewIntent.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: if activity is already running, doesnt matter forground or background, with the help of FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP onNewIntent() is called, I prefer launchmode to SINGLE_TOP

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn't seem to be working. From the source of the Android launcher, onNewIntent() resets the homescreen to the default page. I can't seem to replicate that behavior from starting the launcher from my app

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will Help You,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MainActivity.startActivity(intent);
```